# Calculate mean across dimension in a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, numpy, mean

I have an array `a` like this:

```
a = [[40, 10], [50, 11]]
```

I need to calculate the mean for each dimension separately, the result should be this:

```
[45, 10.5]
```

`45` being the mean of `a[*][0]` and `10.5` the mean of `a[*][1]`.

What is the most elegant way of solving this without using a loop?

Answer (score 162):

`a.mean()` takes an `axis` argument:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([[40, 10], [50, 11]])

In [3]: a.mean(axis=1)     # to take the mean of each row
Out[3]: array([ 25. ,  30.5])

In [4]: a.mean(axis=0)     # to take the mean of each col
Out[4]: array([ 45. ,  10.5])
```

Or, as a standalone function:

```
In [5]: np.mean(a, axis=1)
Out[5]: array([ 25. ,  30.5])
```

The reason your slicing wasn't working is because this is the syntax for slicing:

```
In [6]: a[:,0].mean() # first column
Out[6]: 45.0

In [7]: a[:,1].mean() # second column
Out[7]: 10.5
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. What does `In [n]:` means? is this part of the code?

Comment: I'm using numpy, so line 2 and 3 works great, but with `axis=0` instead of `axis=1`

Comment: @otmezger `axis=0` is on the next line.  I edited to show more info, refresh, perhaps?

Comment: @otmezger You're welcome.  Take note that many numpy array methods take an axis argument just like this.

Comment: @askewchan: what does `mean = np.mean(a, axis=(0,2,3)) mean? `knowing that the input tensor (a) is of shape (batch,channel,width,height) ?

Answer (score 16):

Here is a non-numpy solution:

```
>>> a = [[40, 10], [50, 11]]
>>> [float(sum(l))/len(l) for l in zip(*a)]
[45.0, 10.5]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you do this a lot, [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) is the way to go.

If for some reason you can't use NumPy:

```
>>> map(lambda x:sum(x)/float(len(x)), zip(*a))
[45.0, 10.5]
```