# doing math operations using numpy in python3

Tags: numpy, math

I have a `numpy` `array` like this example:

example:

```
arr = array([[31, 18],
       [ 27,  9],
       [21, 20]])
```

and I want to get the `mean` of every inner list separately and also
`standard deviation` of every inner list separately. until here I would
have 2 lists (for mean and std) and every list would have 3 items (one
per inner list in arr).
then I will multiply every single item of std list and then will add
mean list and new std list item by item. so at the end the results
would be a list with 3 items.
here is the steps for the example:

```
std = [9.19238815542512, 12.7279220613579, 0.707106781186548]
std2 = [18.3847763108502, 25.4558441227157, 1.4142135623731]
mean = [24.5, 18, 20.5]
```

and here is the expected output:

```
final = [42.8847763108502, 43.4558441227157, 21.9142135623731]
```

to make such results I wrote the following code in python:

```
import numpy as np
for item in arr:
    mean, std = [np.mean(), np.std()*2]
    results = mean + std
```

but it does not return expected output. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You'll get further in numpy if you think in terms of dimensions or axes,and shapes. Your example is (3,2) shaped.  Look at the function docs.  Experiment.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15820007/7389264)  to [Calculate mean across dimension in a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15819980/7389264) should cover this question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your code. First, you are calling `np.mean` without an argument, which should result in an error. Instead, you want to call either `arr.mean(...)` or `np.mean(arr, ...)`. Second, you are overwriting the `result` variable in every iteration of the loop. You probably wanted to declare the result arrays outside the loop, and use `list.append` to add to them.

However, there is a specialized solution to your question built in to Numpy: many Numpy functions have an `axis` parameter that lets you take a mean along one axis of an array.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0, 100],
                [1, 101],
                [2, 102]])

arr.mean(axis=0) # => [1, 101]
arr.mean(1) # => [50, 51, 52]
```

To tell which axis to use, remember that the given axis will be deleted. So for a 3 by 2 array, operating over axis 0 will leave you with a length-2 array, and using axis 1 will leave length 3.

Numpy also lets you perform elementwise arithmetic on arrays<sup>1</sup> of the same shape, or between arrays and numbers.<sup>2</sup>

```
np.array([1, 2, 3]) + np.array([4, 5, 6]) # => [5, 7, 9]
```

Using those hints, it should be pretty straightforward to get the results you want.

---

The [Numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) is a great place to start if you want to learn the ins and outs of Numpy's features.

<sup>1</sup> You can also add arrays to lists, and add lists using `np.add`. This applies to anything Numpy considers "array-like," such as tuples.

<sup>2</sup> Numpy also allows certain operations between different shaped arrays, using its [broadcasting rule](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), but that's a bit off-topic here.