# Calculate mean of each 2d array in a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have an numpy array as following:

```
b = numpy.array([[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [[1,1,1],[3,3,3]]])
print(b)
[[[1 2 3]
  [4 5 6]]

 [[1 1 1]
  [3 3 3]]]
```

now I wan't to calculate the mean of each 2-d array in the array. for e.g.

```
numpy.mean(b[0])
>>> 3.5
numpy.mean(b[1])
>>> 2.0
```

How do I do this without using a for loop?

Comment: `np.mean(b, axis=0)` or simply `b.mean(axis=0)` or `axis=1` depending if you want to average rows or columns.

Comment: Or `b.mean(0)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate mean across dimension in a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819980/calculate-mean-across-dimension-in-a-2d-array)

Comment: No, none of these address the question I had. Please note that I have an array of 2D arrays. Not a 2D array.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this would give you your expected output

By passing multi-dim in `axis` - [see doc for more about `axis` param](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)

```
b.mean(axis=(1,2))
array([3.5, 2. ])
```

Comment: skip the loop. no point in looping for an operational like this on a numpy array

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. I understand the FOR loop, but can you please explain the first solution you described?

Comment: @PaulH yes, removed it.

Comment: @SaqibAli It will performed mean on multiple dims as passed.

Answer (score 2):

`np.mean()` can take in parameters for the axis, so according to your use, you can do either of the following

```
print("Mean of each column:")
print(x.mean(axis=0))
print("Mean of each row:")
print(x.mean(axis=1))
```

Comment: To expand on this: Axis of 0 is rows, 1 is columns. You iterate over rows to compute the sum of each column and you iterate over columns to compute the sum of each row which is how you get the code above.