# How to get mean value with 1D array and 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, statistics

Here is two lists: list = [[1, 2], [3, 4]] and list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4]

I would like to calculate the mean of the lists. This is my code thus far and outputs:

```
 def summary(x):
      mean1 = np.mean(x)

      Dict = {"mean":mean1}
 return Dict

summary([1, 2, 2, 3, 4])
My output is == {'mean': 2.4}

summary([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
My output is == error
```

I would just like to know what should i change to my code so that 2D arrays also work if i give it as input and not only just 1D arrays?

I have seen that i should insert (x, axis=1) but then it only works for 2Darray and not again for the 1D array.

I would like the 2D mean to give me output: 'mean': [1.5, 3.5]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate mean across dimension in a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819980/calculate-mean-across-dimension-in-a-2d-array)

Comment: @UmairMubeen i have tried the np.mean(x, axis=1) but then it only works for the 2D array and when i try to run the 1D array it does not work

Comment: `def summary(list):` should be `def summary(x):`

Comment: @Nick i have changed it. I would just like the function to give for my 2D array output:  'mean': [1.5, 3.5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the summary definition instead of `list` you want to have `x` as parameter.

With this it works fine for me:

```
import numpy as np
def summary(x):
    mean1 = np.mean(x)

    Dict = {"mean":mean1}
    return Dict

a = summary([1, 2, 2, 3, 4])
print(a)
b = summary([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
print(b)
```

Result is:

```
{'mean': 2.4}
{'mean': 2.5}
```

**[Update]**

If you want to have the mean along a specific axis you can do it like the following. You have to check the array shape, because you want it in direction 1, which is not prsent for a 1D array.

```
import numpy as np
def summary(x):
    arr = np.array(x)
    if len(arr.shape) == 2:
        mean1 = np.mean(arr, axis=1)
    else:
        mean1 = np.mean(arr)

    Dict = {"mean":mean1}
    return Dict

a = summary([1, 2, 2, 3, 4])
print(a)
b = summary([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
print(b)
```

which returns

```
{'mean': 2.4}
{'mean': array([1.5, 3.5])}
```

Comment: For the 2D one it should give output 'mean': [1.5, 3.5] and with that code it does not

Comment: Is there a way the output remove the word "array" like just show the "mean": 1.5,3.5

Comment: you can print it like this: `print(f'mean: {b["mean"]}')` - `mean: [1.5 3.5]` is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
import numpy as np

def summary(x):
      mean1 = np.mean(x)
      Dict = {"mean":mean1}
      return Dict

print(summary([1, 2, 2, 3, 4]))

print(summary([[1, 2], [3, 4]]))
```

Comment: For the 2D one it should give output 'mean': [1.5, 3.5] and with that code it does not